# UICollectionview section and rows from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

I'm trying to have sections for each meal in UICollectionview from JSON.I just couldn't do it

```
{
  "meals" : [
    {
      "id" : 279,
      "unit" : "حبة",
      "disable" : "0",
      "created_at" : "2017-03-06 19:17:23",
      "time" : "فوري",
      "small" : "0",
      "type" : "2",
      "desc" : "",
      "price" : "6",
      "image" : "a4f730f447e753a995e342e12446ab1958bdb5c3136b6.jpg",
      "family_id" : "115",
      "updated_at" : "2017-03-06 19:17:23",
      "deleted_at" : null,
      "medium" : "0",
      "large" : "0",
      "name" : "ساندوتش فلافل كعك بالسمسم "
    },
    {
      "id" : 280,
      "unit" : "حبة",
      "disable" : "0",
      "created_at" : "2017-03-06 19:21:51",
      "time" : "فوري",
      "small" : "0",
      "type" : "2",
      "desc" : "",
      "price" : "5",
      "image" : "1c65581aa774203a4335bc6d93fe2b6358bdb6f3edb23.jpg",
      "family_id" : "115",
      "updated_at" : "2017-03-06 19:22:27",
      "deleted_at" : null,
      "medium" : "0",
      "large" : "0",
      "name" : "سندويش فلافل عربي اصناف "
    },
```

The `type` is the section name of the meals. Every meal will have a section either 1 ,2 ,3,4

Now I set the rows of the UICollectionview like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if meals.count > 0 {
            self.collectionView.backgroundView = nil
            return meals.count
        }
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          width: self.collectionView.bounds.size.width,
                          height: self.collectionView.bounds.size.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)

        noDataLabel.text = "تقدر تطلب اي شي من \(nameOfShop.text!)"
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.collectionView.backgroundView = noDataLabel

        return 0

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mealsCell", for: indexPath) as! MealCollectionViewCell

        let entry = meals[indexPath.row]

        cell.mealName.text = entry.meal_name
        cell.mealPrice.text = "\(entry.price) ريال"

        cell.mealImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
        return cell

    }
```

And here is how I get the data from API

```
 let name = subJson["name"].stringValue
            let price = subJson["price"].stringValue
            let logo = subJson["image"].stringValue
            let id = subJson["id"].stringValue
           let logoString = "http://app.com/upload/img/\(logo)"

            let info = Meals(meal_id: id, Logo: logoString, meal_name: name, price: price)

            self.meals.append(info)
```

Sorry for the long code nut I think I should explain more.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What's not working?

Comment: I want to add sections for the meals. the section name is the `type` from json. each meal comes with `type`

Comment: `allShops` is your array of data? Then the easiest would be to organise it as an array of arrays, or a dictionary with arrays (type being the key for each array). That way you can just lookup the array for each section directly in your dataSource delegate methods: instead of `allShops.count` you then have `allShops[section].count` and instead of `let shop = allShops[indexPath.row]` you'll have `let shop = allShops[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`

Comment: I apologize can you check my question again it's not this code I copied the wrong code...

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of arrays to model your dataSource. Instead of `self.meals.append(info)`, initialise `meals` as an array of arrays, then:

```
let type = subJson["type"].intValue 
self.meals[type-1].append(info)  // note here that you may need to adjust depending on the possible values of type.
```

Then in `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)`:

```
if meals[section].count > 0 {
    etc...
}
```

In `numberOfSections(in:)`:

```
return meals.count
```

In `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`:

```
let entry = meals[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Alternatively, if `type` isn't a consecutive list of integers, a `Dictionary` might be a better way to store your `meals`:

```
var meals = Dictionary<String, Array<Meals>>()
for type in types {
     meals[type] = []
}

...

self.meals[type] = info
```

That way you don't have to worry about having the right number of arrays to start with, if one `type` value is missing in the JSON response it will still work. The `UITableView` dataSource methods then need to be changed to map the section number to your type keys.

Comment: thank you for your answer!! I just didn't get you when you said initialise meals as an array of arrays

Comment: well, somewhere in your code you declare the property `meals`. Make sure it's an array of arrays. E.g. `var meals = [[Meals]]()`

Comment: you need double brackets so you get a separate array for each type. And again, important: I'm creating section values of 0, 1, 2, 3, ... Make sure if `type` is 1, 2, 3, 4 that you use `type - 1` to get the corresponding sections. If `type` aren't consecutive integers, then you might want to create an `Enum` mapping your types.

Comment: I get error in  if meals[section].count > 0  fatal error: Index out of range I think because type is a string. So I changed the `type` from number to names how can I change this to type with a string `self.meals[type-1].append(info)`

Comment: I changed the type from Int to String in my web service

Comment: Set some breakpoints and check the `self.meals` array after you've created it. Probably `meals.count` isn't returning the correct number of sections. Make sure to properly initialise `meals` with empty arrays, for example `var meals = [[Meals]](count:4, repeatedValue:[])`

Comment: `meals.count` is returning 0 and I initialize it as you said  `var meals = [[Meals]]()`

Comment: You need to make `meals` in the initialisation contain as many arrays as you will have types: `for type in types {meals.append([])}` (or the initialiser I mentioned above if you have fixed number of types). So you're sure it's the correct length. Then don't forget the `self.meals[type-1].append(info)`

Comment: but type is a string now and each restaurant has meals that have different sections

Comment: I added the Dictionary option above, easier if type is a string. Anyway, that's the general idea how to work with sections and rows, adapt to the exact situation you have.

Comment: I changed the initialization and added the loop but the errors appeared `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Array<Meals>]'with an index of type 'Int'` in all over. Thank you for your effort I'll see what I can do

Comment: well that means somewhere you typecast `type` to `Int`. I thought you said it was `String`.